# Cannot open https://www.rba.gov.au from Windows 2012

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, windows-server-2012, .net-framework

We have an application that downloads https://www.rba.gov.au/rss/rss-cb-exchange-rates.xml daily to get exchange rates. It stopped working a few days ago, we found that above URL doesn't open in IE while it does in Chrome.
My understanding is that the App, which is developed using .NET framework, would certainly use the same thing under the hood as IE, thus it couldn't download the file either.
Below is the error I get when visiting the site using IE, I'm sure that all TLS version are enabled:
[image]

And below is the error I get when I try to download the file through powershell/.net:
[image]

Then I tested the url using ssllabs.com and got the following result. It says fatal error is ruturned if client is IE11/Win 8 (I believe Windows 2012 and Windows 8 belong to the same family, so fatal error would occur to server 2012 too).
[image]

But I'm thinking there must be something I can do, some setting I can change to fix this issue? I would like to avoid Upgrading the OS to server 2016 just for this issue. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's Enhanced Security for you: not an exact science. I were you, I'd disable it from Server Manager for Admin and other user accounts with admin rights, just to check if your problem is solved.

Comment: I just checked enhanced security setting, it is off. So I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.rba.gov.au&s=202.14.155.102) the only two ciphers supported by the server are `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` and  `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. Based on the [information from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1) these ciphers are not supported by Windows 8.1 and 2012.

> But I'm thinking there must be something I can do, some setting I can change to fix this issue?

Unfortunately not. Your are facing inherent limitations of the OS you use combined with a broken server setup (too few usable ciphers, domain has IPv6 address but SSL on IPv6 fails). You can install a different browser like Chrome or Firefox though to access the site since these browsers come with their own TLS stack which supports these ciphers.

Comment: Hmm. I certainly did not expect that this is not possible.

Comment: @DavidDai: Again, these limitations are specific to the build-in TLS stack which is unfortunately used by .NET too. If you use OpenSSL/BoringSSL as Chrome does or NSS as Firefox does then you don't have these limitations.

Comment: Thank you. I still find it a bit a hard to believe that there's no way to add additional cipher support to Windows.